# Need to replace only two or more space with comma using shell script

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I have a text file with the following values.

```
Id      unit    Date             status
KGE1    1222    21-12-19 16:20   Deployed
KGE2    1222    21-12-19 16:20   Pending
```

I want to replace only the consecutive space with comma.
I am using the below  command but it is adding comma in between date and time as well. Please guide.

```
sed 's/ \{1,\}/,/g' txncount.txt > csvcount.txt
```

Output:

```
KGE1,1222,21-12-19,16:20,Deployed
KGE2,1222,21-12-19,16:20,Pending
KGE3,1222,21-12-19,16:21,Email_Sent
KGE4,1222,21-12-19,15:00,Pending
KGE5,1222,21-12-19,15:10,Deployed
```

Expected Output:

```
KGE1,1222,21-12-19 16:20,Deployed
KGE2,1222,21-12-19 16:20,Pending
KGE3,1222,21-12-19 16:21,Email_Sent
KGE4,1222,21-12-19 15:00,Pending
KGE5,1222,21-12-19 15:10,Deployed
```

It should replace only consecutive comma that is tow or more space with comma.

Comment: So change the `\{1,\}` quantifier to `\{2,\}`?

Comment: Thanks. It worked

Comment: Or else `sed -E "s/  +/,/g" file`

Answer (score 1):

It's `<txncount.txt sed -r 's/ {2,}/,/g' >csvcount.txt`